# Android create file exception EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android

I cannot write to the internal storage of an android device or emulator.
I am able write to a file in the external storage directory.

I am getting this exception
    EACCES (Permission denied) 
on the createNewFile call.

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is in the right place in my manifest

```
public static Boolean writeFile(String filename, String data)
{
      try 
      {
        File file = new File(filename);
        // If file does not exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) 
        {
            Log.d("MyLog","file doesn't exist, creating");
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(data);
        bw.close();

        //Log.d("Success","Success");
        return true;
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("MyLog","writeFile fail, error:"+e.getMessage());
        return false;
      }
}
```

I have tried numerous paths:

```
filename=Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/"+"test.dat";
filename=Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/"+"test.dat";
filename="data/data/com.android.emsi/testnew.txt";
```

the only thing that will work is:
filename=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"test.dat";

Comment: You can only write to the internal storage directory of your app. Not to other directories of the internal storage like you tried. Use getFilesDir() for app specific directory. That external permission does ofcourse nothing with internal memory.

Comment: Maybe part of the problem is that I am in a JUnit test case, not in an activity. My test extends InstrumentationTestCase. and I am doing this to create the context. Context c=getInstrumentation().getContext();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```